Linux real-time kernel frequently kills my app
I'm developing a near real-time application, that forwards messages in a endless loop(no yield, no sleep, no wait).
The messages come from shared memory, go to another blocks of shared memory, so my prog doesn't need to wait anything such as NIC.
I need the message delays are as less as possible, so I bound my program with the last core of a VPS that has 8 CPU cores, and change my program's scheduling policy to SCHED_FIFO and priority to 50.
It really should use the 100% time of one single core, is not a ill form. Meanwhile I think there are rest 7 cores can be used by OS and other interrupt handllers, my prog should'nt result the system stalled.
I'm tesing it on a VPS that has 8 cores, and I installed Debian-12 Bookworm and a real-time kernel(linux-image-rt-amd64).
But sometimes my program was killed by kernel, with some warnning as following:

kernel: rcu: INFO: rcu_preempt self-detected stall on CPU
kernel: rcu:         7-....: (1 GPs behind) idle=ee1c/1/0x4000000000000000 softirq=0/0 fqs=2197 rcuc=5254 jiffies(starved)
kernel:         (t=5250 jiffies g=414049 q=21537 ncpus=8)
kernel: CPU: 7 PID: 4482 Comm: my-app Not tainted 6.1.0-27-rt-amd64 #1  Debian 6.1.115-1
kernel: Hardware name: Tencent Cloud CVM, BIOS seabios-1.9.1-qemu-project.org 04/01/2014
kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7fd5631d5367
kernel: Code: 44 00 00 48 89 ee 89 df b8 e5 00 00 00 0f 05 48 3d 00 f0 ff ff 76 df 48 89 c2 eb c9 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 48 8b 05 31 2b 10 00 <48> 8b 80 e0 02 00 00 48 85 c0 74 15 48 83 ec 08 ff d0 85 c0 75 23
kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffe790abb78 EFLAGS: 00000246
kernel: RAX: 00007fd564077ac0 RBX: 180b1208a6ff6dd8 RCX: 00007fd560886000
kernel: RDX: 00007fd560db8340 RSI: 00007ffe790abb80 RDI: 0000000000000000
kernel: RBP: 00007ffe790ac788 R08: 000000000001f3a7 R09: 00000000ffffffff
kernel: R10: 00007ffe79119080 R11: 000000000027e020 R12: 180b1208a6ff6dd8
kernel: R13: 00007ffe790ac0f0 R14: 00007ffe790ac0f0 R15: 00007ffe790ac538
kernel: FS:  00007fd5622e1000 GS:  0000000000000000

I never used a real-time kernel before.
What does this mean? Does kernel think that my program should'nt continuously execute for long time?
How to let the kernel don't think of my prog as a ill form?

Have a look at Using RCU’s CPU Stall Detector and check if the stuff about CPU-bound real-time tasks applies in your case.
